# Allow mac smart quotes in regex validation on html form

Tags: regex, parsley.js

We use the following parsley regex validation on our checkout page but mac device users (iPhones, etc.) are running into trouble when using apostrophes.  Is there a way to allow for smart quote type elements in regex?

```
^(?!.*[0-9]{12,})[a-zA-Z0-9)(,'-/\&.#? ]*$
```

As an example, on a pc the validation allows

```
Father's Day
```

but when entered on an iPhone as

```
Father’s Day
```

validation comes back stating there is a problem.

Comment: I think you will have to look into [unicode & regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes).

Comment: The unicode may have worked but I found that if I pasted in the quotes and apostrophe from a Word document that parsley would accept that as valid in regex. Not sure that's the ultimate solution but it works for my specific situation.